# linearly independent complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

We have to construct a basis for $\mathbb{C} [z]\ |\ deg \leq 1$ where $\ z = x + iy $ and therefore $ z \in \mathbb{C} $
and I think $ \{1,z\}  $ is correct but a colleague said it has to be  $ \{1,z, \overline{z}\}$

But isn't $ \{1,z, \overline{z}\}$ linear dependent?
Can't I represent the real part of the complex numbers with a multiple of 1?

Comment: $\dim(\mathbb{C}_1[X])=2$ so a basis should have $2$ elements.

Comment: Ok perfect, just what I thought.

Comment: A basis over $\Bbb R$ then? A basis over $\Bbb C$ is $\{1\}$

Comment: $\overline{z}$ is not an element of the space.

Comment: You got to be really careful whether or not your scalars are real or complex. Because two complex numbers can be lin independent if the scalars are real, but linear dependent if complex scalars are allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\{1, z, \overline{z} \}$ is indeed a linearly dependent family, given that $\overline{z} = 2\Re(z) \times 1 -1 \times z$, from the formula $z + \overline{z} = 2\Re(z)$